# Properties missing in JSON data deserialization with Model in .NET Core-6.0

Tags: .net, .net-6.0, json-deserialization, json-serialization, c#-10.0

my project is  .NET 6.0.

I have an issue After deserializing the  JSON data with **PriceVM** class  `Show, Ticket` fields are missing in the postman output.

this is the JSON output without deserializing with model

```
{
    "traceId": "fhregtkgregtireuiti3t",
     "data": {
        "airPrice":[
            {
                "key":"kjewqerlewqwwq",
                "show":true,
                "showSpecified":true,
                "departure":"2022-06-28T19:08:00.000+01:00",
                "solution":[
                    {
                        "ticket":false,
                        "ticketSpecified":false,
                        "origin":"JED",
                        "exchange":false
                    },
                    {
                        "ticket":false,
                        "ticketSpecified":false,
                        "origin":"MND",
                        "exchange":false
                    },
                ]   
            }
        
        ]
     
     }
}
```

I created below class with above JSON result

```
public class PriceVM{

 [JsonProperty("traceId")]
 public string TraceId {get;set;}

 [JsonProperty("data")]
 public Data Data {get;set;}
 
}

public class Data {

 [JsonProperty("airPrice")]
 public IEnumerable<AirPrice> AirPrice {get;set;}

}

public class AirPrice{
 
 [JsonProperty("airPrice")]
 public string Key {get;set;}

 [JsonProperty("show")]
 public bool Show {get;set;}

 [JsonProperty("showSpecified")]
 public bool ShowSpecified {get;set;}

 [JsonProperty("departure")]
 public DateTime Departure {get;set;}

 [JsonProperty("solution")]
 public List<Solution> Solution {get;set;}

} 

public class Solution{

 [JsonProperty("ticket")]    
 public bool Ticket {get;set;}

 [JsonProperty("ticketSpecified")]    
 public bool TicketSpecified {get;set;}

 [JsonProperty("origin")]
 public string Origin {get;set;}

 [JsonProperty("exchange")]
 public bool Exchange {get;set;}

}
```

I get the above-structured JSON data from API in this function

```
public async Task<PriceVM> Handle(PriceQuery request)
{
    
 var response= await client.PostAsJsonAsync<ADT>("url",request);
 response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
 string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
 
  var airPrice = (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PriceVM>(responseBody, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,    
 }));

}
```

if I deserialize with the above method output is as below
**Show, Ticket** properties are missing

```
 {
        "traceId": "fhregtkgregtireuiti3t",
         "data": {
            "airPrice":[
                {
                    "key":"kjewqerlewqwwq",
                    "showSpecified":true,
                    "departure":"2022-06-28T19:08:00.000+01:00",
                    "solution":[
                        {
                            "ticketSpecified":false,
                            "origin":"JED",
                            "exchange":false
                        },
                        {
                            "ticketSpecified":false,
                            "origin":"MND",
                            "exchange":false
                        },
                    ]   
                }
            
            ]
         
         }
    }
```

// endpoint

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("price")]
public async Task<ActionResult<PriceVM>> AirPrice( [FromBody] ADT dto)
{

    var result = await pricesrvice.Handle(dto);
    
    return Ok(result);
}
```

but when I debug the API request; in the controller endpoint I can view the **result** has `Show, Ticket` properties and their values as well.

if I deserialized the JSON result like below all fields are in postmen output

```
var airPrice = (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseBody, new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
           DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,    
    }));
```

output

```
  {
        "traceId": "fhregtkgregtireuiti3t",
         "data": {
            "airPrice":[
                {
                    "key":"kjewqerlewqwwq",
                    "show":true,
                    "showSpecified":true,
                    "departure":"2022-06-28T19:08:00.000+01:00",
                    "solution":[
                        {
                            "ticket":false,
                            "ticketSpecified":false,
                            "origin":"JED",
                            "exchange":false
                        },
                        {
                            "ticket":false,
                            "ticketSpecified":false,
                            "origin":"MND",
                            "exchange":false
                        },
                    ]   
                }
            
            ]
         
         }
    }
```

The error is if name and value of 2 near property is same it return one property . example

**ticket ,ticketSpecified**

to sortout this i add below configuration in

> Program.cs

file

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
                options.Filters.Add<ApiExceptionFilterAttribute>())
                    .AddFluentValidation()

.AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

**// Added code**
    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver()
  {
        IgnoreIsSpecifiedMembers = false,
    };
});
```

then **it returns All properties**

but when I log in via UI can not log in

but no error shown in the console in the development and production environment

if I comment these code can login and work as usual

```
options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver()
  {
        IgnoreIsSpecifiedMembers = false,
    };
```

please help me to sort out this error

Comment: Please show the raw JSON response

Comment: @Charlieface JSON response added

Comment: `JsonPropertyName` and `JsonProperty` are for two different libraries: System.Text.Json and Newtonsoft.Json. You are using `JsonConvert` which is from the latter, but the attributes are `JsonPropertyName`

Comment: @Charlieface properties are missing after a return. but when we deserialize to model all properties and their values have.

Comment: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(` returns a JObject which has all the properties, as it is dynamic. On the other hand `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PriceVM>(` won't map properly due to the issue with `JsonPropertyName`

Comment: @Charlieface is JsonProperty overcome that issue?

Comment: I don't know for sure but it's a good start: change `JsonPropertyName` to `JsonProperty`

Comment: @Charlieface  if  I change 
 [JsonPropertyName("show")]
 public bool Show {get;set;}   to 

 [JsonPropertyName("show")]
 public bool Txt {get;set;}

it returns the value of show property in Txt property

var options = new JsonSerializerOptions{
            PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true

        };

in below serialization
var airprice= System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<PriceVM>(responseBody, options);

Comment: You shouldn't need the change at all if you are using `JsonSerializer.Deserialize` But above you are using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` not `JsonSerializer.Deserialize`. stop mixing the two libraries.

Comment: @Charlieface are there any configurations that have to stop ignoring the default value of the property when deserializing using  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject setting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last issue is it returns data in pascal  Case because of **DefaultContractResolver**. but by default, it returns data in  camel Case

to overcome that issue I configure `Program. cs`

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
                options.Filters.Add<ApiExceptionFilterAttribute>())
                    .AddFluentValidation()

.AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

**// Replace below code **
    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver()
  {
        IgnoreIsSpecifiedMembers = false,
    };

 // with

 options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
        {
            IgnoreIsSpecifiedMembers = true,
        };
});
```